# Pool hard cap violation? Android images in React native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image, react-native-render-html

I have an Image component inside a modal in react native .64, and it works perfectly on iOS, but with Android I get a an error (for instance: `Pool hard cap violation? Hard cap = 201326592 Used size = 200030968 Free size = 0 Request size = 4194000`)

I've done research, and some people have had good luck setting `android:large_heap="true"` but it slows my app down to a crawl on that page. How do I get images to show fullscreen in a modal for Android in React Native?

My image (that works on iOS):

```
<Modal supportedOrientations={['landscape', 'portrait']} animationType='fade' visible={!!modalImage} style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF', position: 'relative'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity hitSlop={{ top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20}} style={{position: 'absolute', top: '5%', right: '5%', width: 20, height: 20, zIndex: 999}} onPress={() => setModalImage(null)}>
            <Image style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} source={require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Close/close-dark-mode.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <ReactNativeZoomableView
            ref={zoomableRef}
            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#000'}}
            maxZoom={3}
            minZoom={1}
            zoomStep={3}
            onShiftingBefore={_onShiftBefore}
            onShiftingAfter={_onShiftAfter}
          >
            <Image onError={(e) => console.log('error', e.nativeEvent.error)} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} resizeMode='contain' resizeMethod='resize' source={{ uri: `https://testsite.com${HtmlTextParser(modalImage)}` }} />
          </ReactNativeZoomableView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: This is a limitation from fresco; a React Native bug. [Mentioned in the FAQ](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/faq#long-image-cannot-show-in-full-screen-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

In Android, in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`  add the line `android:largeHeap="true"` after `<application --insert here-- ></application>`

Hope this helps anyone else who is facing this problem!

Comment: I addressed this in my question. It slows the app to a crawl.

Comment: It's still hasn't fixed react native has issues showing large images Fullscreen it's a limitation on fresco library you need to downsize the image using React Native Image component

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Android Emulator with small images.
I changed the build architecture in app build.gradle from x86 to x86_64 and the problem's gone